# How to do integration test with all the module in maven?

Tags: maven, jetty, hornetq

For example, I have a maven project with 2 modules. a REST service module, a hornetq jms module.

The Manual way would be:

1. Run an embedded jetty server application
2. Run an embedded hornetq server
3. Sending a PUT request to the REST server (REST server as a hornetq producer push the request message to a hornetq queue)
4. Start a hornetq consumer to recieve the queued message

How do I perform the integration test with them using maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is `maven-failsafe-plugin` (see doc http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html). It allows you to

1. Start applications in `pre-integration-test` phase (e.g., jetty or hornetq)
2. Perform the tests in `integration-test` phase
3. Stop the applications in `post-integration-test` phase
4. Evaluate the results of the tests in `verify` phase (e.g., to fail the build, to generate JUnit report)

Check out the examples in the provided link.

In your particular case, you would start all the servers in the `pre-integration-test` phase (by using `hornetq-maven-plugin` and `jetty-maven-plugin` and possibly `maven-antrun-plugin`) and then stop them in the `post-integration-test` phase.

I recommend to execute the PUT request from Java by using JUnit or TestNG framework because it perfectly integrates with `maven-failsafe-plugin`. If possible, start (and stop) the hornetq consumer programmatically as a part of the JUnit/TestNG test because there you would `assert` the result.

Some other resources:

- http://avianey.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/maven-it-case-background-process.html
- How to start Hornetq example: https://github.com/hornetq/maven-hornetq-plugin/blob/master/examples/integration-test-example/pom.xml